# What is http://www.semanticoverflow.com/? An old se1 site?

Tags: discussion

There are no links at the bottom of the pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is (from the HTML):

`<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">`

Although it doesn't seem to be in [this list of current SE1.0 sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) which is strange.

Comment: you can also check for any of the new non-bug-fix additional features in SE2.0, like how the privileges page doesn't exist: http://www.semanticoverflow.com/privileges/

Comment: That list of SE 1.0 sites wasn't ever necessarily complete.  There are probably many more SE 1.0 sites that exist/existed that never made it onto that list, either because the owner didn't choose to publicize their site that way and/or nobody else discovered it and put it on the list.